# How long should itl take to install elementary OS?

Tags: system-installation

Firstly I don't know so much about PCs and OSs. I have HP Envy with windows 10, but I want to replace it with  elementary OS. I followed their instructions on the website, I selected Install elementary and it said it will take a long time. Is it normal to exceed 10 hrs and still be installing?!

Comment: 10 hours for downloading the install image or installing the OS?

Comment: It isinstalling full elementary os in a 32gb usb pen drive. Can anybody help me with this

Answer (score 2):

Elementary OS installing takes about 6-10 minutes. This time may vary depending on the capabilities of your computer. But, the installation doesn't last 10 hours.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else having this problem, I didn't know why elementary almost seemed frozen, but eventually realized I had an error message hidden behind the installation screen.